# HTML5 m3u / asx stream player

Tags: html, audio, stream, m3u, asx

I was wondering if it is possible to play a radio stream via m3u or asx on a HTML 5 player?
Google doesn't give me any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it isn't possible in HTML5 yet. I think most streams are MP3. You can try to convert the ASX stream to an MP3 via PHP. Meanwhile you can load it via Javascript/HTML5 in your browser.

Comment: Could you give more details please about converting/loading in my browser?